# How to create shared component / application processes from a PL/SQL script in APEX?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I was following this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aeapi/oracle-apex-api-reference.pdf) about apex 21.2 API, and I don't know how to create an application process that is located in the shared component of an APEX application using APEX API.

Essentially I want to create a PL/SQL process that is called after each page submit but create it from sqlplus.

Is there a PL/SQL package that can do this, or the only way is using the UI ?

Comment: it seems that when you export an apex app the shared components are also exported so for me importing an app with an already existing application process solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Application Process (under Shared Components), with the Point set to **On Submit: After Page Submission - After Computations and Validations**.

The code for the process can call, for example, a procedure in a package you have created.

Comment: I was asking about if there if an APEX API package that can do this for me, for the purpose of automating it. I already know how to create it in the UI.

Comment: Hi Tayeb, there is no supported way to do that at this time. There is a related idea which anyone can vote for and comment on: https://apexapps.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/fr/r/FR-1831